# how to read junit result on travis log by sed?

Tags: unix, sed

I add 3 sample trace by `echo`.

I read log file

and I want use `sed`. I want find if any error in my all test.

**run.sh**

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

echo "[1565214900.443][SEVERE]: Timed out receiving message from renderer: -0.011"
echo "[INFO] Tests run: 4, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 7.16 s - in com.github.noraui.browser.AuthUT"
echo "[INFO] Running com.github.noraui.gherkin.GherkinConditionedLoopedStepUT"

curl -s "https://api.travis-ci.org/jobs/${TRAVIS_JOB_ID}/log.txt?deansi=true" > nonaui.log

counterFailures=$(sed -n 's:.*\[INFO\] Tests run\: 4, Failures\:\(.*\), Errors\: 0, Skipped\: 0, Time elapsed.*:\1:p' nonaui.log | head -n 1)
echo "******** counter: $counterFailures"
```

**my restult is**

```
$ ./run.sh
[1565214900.443][SEVERE]: Timed out receiving message from renderer: -0.011
[INFO] Tests run: 4, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 7.16 s - in com.github.noraui.browser.AuthUT
[INFO] Running com.github.noraui.gherkin.GherkinConditionedLoopedStepUT
******** counter: 
The command "./run.sh" exited with 0.
```

My sample is online [here](https://github.com/NoraUi/cicd) and My sample result is online [here](https://travis-ci.org/NoraUi/cicd)

Comment: Providing an example of nonaui.log would be great.

Comment: noraui.log is 3 `echo` sample. you can find my sample online: https://github.com/NoraUi/cicd and my sample result: https://travis-ci.org/NoraUi/cicd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should work:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

echo "[1565214900.443][SEVERE]: Timed out receiving message from renderer: -0.011" > nonaui.log
echo "[INFO] Tests run: 4, Failures: 10, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 7.16 s - in com.github.noraui.browser.AuthUT" >> nonaui.log
echo "[INFO] Running com.github.noraui.gherkin.GherkinConditionedLoopedStepUT" >> nonaui.log

counterFailures=$(sed -n 's/.*\[INFO\] Tests run: 4, Failures:\(.*\), Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed.*/\1/p' nonaui.log | head -n 1)
echo "******** counter: $counterFailures"
```

I am guessing that the echo statements at the top of your code are samples because you've not shared them explicitly. This is what I see when I run it:

```
$ ./run.sh 
******** counter:  10
$
```

Two things:

1. You used `:` as a sed delimiter, but your pattern also has a colon in it
2. Square brackets also mean something for a RE. You need to escape them

Comment: have you a idea if I have more one `echo "[INFO] Tests run: 4, Failures...`? I want get all occurrences. I try with `\g` but do not work.

Answer (score 1):

Your regexp pattern is too specific to work on any input.

sed :

```
counterFailures=$(sed -n 's/.*Tests run.*Failures: \([0-9]+\).*/\1/p' nonaui.log | head -n 1)
```

GNU grep :

```
counterFailures=$(grep -oP 'Tests run.*Failures: \K[0-9]+' nonaui.log | head -n 1)
```